# Images on latex not appearing

Tags: graphics

I cannot seem to get the images to appear on latex. I get no error messages and, it has no problems compiling. However, the produced (.pdf) which is what I am using, does not have the image. Essentially, everything I am using is in

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,epsf,portrait,times,epsfig]{article}

\usepackage[dvips]{graphics}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.0cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.5in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{16.0cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
        \includegraphics{C:/Users/Reza/Desktop/Test/Untitled.jpg}
    \label{fig:Untitled}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I am using Texniccenter, and using LaTeX=>PDF. Help please!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). I took the liberty to format your post a little. See [this link for more details on available formatting](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help). **Please, try to make your example _minimal_, i.e. remove every line from your preamble that is not necessary.** As a solution suggestion, try to move file `Untitled.jpg` to the folder where you `.tex` file is, and use `\includegraphics{Untitled.jpg}`. As well notice that LaTeX might be case-sensitive and `Untitled.jpg` is different from `untitled.jpg`.

Comment: Also take a look at your `.log` file to see if there's a warning or error message.

Comment: The `epsf` and `epsfig` options in the `\documentclass` statement are obsolete. To auto-convert image files in `.jpg` format to `.pdf` -- the preferred format of the `graphicx` package -- be sure to load the `epstopdf` package. By the way, the `\label` instruction inside the `figure` environment won't have any desired effects unless you precede it with a `\caption` statement. (The "label" is associated by hyperref and other packages with the closest "label-able" item. In the case of your MWE, there is no such item so far. Hence, be sure to provide a `\caption` statement before the `\label`.

Comment: You need to install Ghostscript software as written [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130354/latex-image-not-showing-up/277890#277890).

Comment: In my case compiling with `lualatex` instead of `pdflatex` solved the issue.

Answer (score 11):

Your file contains incompatibilities.

You use the packages `graphics` and `graphix`. Only one is needed. In addition, you specify the `dvips` driver for `graphics`. This is not the correct driver if you are using pdflatex (which is what I think you are using).

In addition, you are better off not using complete paths, but rather relative paths. This is what tohecz was suggesting with the `\includegraphics{<filename>}` and placing your picture in the same folder as your `.tex` file.

As an example, the following file (by the way, this is what tohecz meant by minimal example) works:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[]{graphics}
%\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{Untitled.jpg}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If you really want to use the `dvips` and the other options, then your images must be in `.eps` format. This means you must convert your `.jpg` image to `.eps`. In addition, you will have to compile with something of the form  `latex -> dvi -> pdf`.

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly the answer to the original question, but this is the solution that helped in my case, when the other solution did not work.

In my case the figures were not showing up because I was using obsolete additional arguments `natheight` and `natwidth` for the `\includegraphics` command:

```
    \includegraphics[width = 3in, natheight = 400, natwidth = 400]{Figure.jpg}
```

If you are using pdfLaTex (as opposed to `dvi` output, which cannot determine the size of graphics) they are not necessary, so just remove those options and only specify the output width/height if necessary:

```
    \includegraphics[width = 3in]{Figure.jpg}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it was a completely different problem than any other solution I could find. I was using a template with a `.cls` file and inside that template, the following line was written `\AtBeginDocument{\let\includegraphics\NAT@ignore}`. Basically it tells the compiler to ignore the `\includegraphics{}` command. I commented that line and now it works like a charm !