# LaTeX - Image not showing up

Tags: graphics, pdf

I am writing up some coursework using LaTeX, and I wanted to import a diagram, however when I did the image did not appear in the compiled pdf. The image has been exported as a eps file, and also as a pdf, both of which had the same result. (Although the PDF also required me to provide bounding box figures, as latex couldn't fetch them from the file). I am including the graphic like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[dvips]{geometry,color,graphicx}
\geometry{a4paper}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=300pt]{figure.eps}
    \caption{caption}
    \label{label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Is `figure.eps` in the present working directory of the `LaTeX` file you are compiling?

Comment: Remove the extension (*.eps) and make sure it is in the same directory as the TeX file.

Comment: What options are you passing to the graphicx package?

Comment: Most likely the following will provide a solution: [Why can't `pdflatex` print EPS figures?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/383/5764)

Comment: @dustin Yes it is.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Just [dvips]

Comment: Can you provide a MWE?

Comment: @DAN I feel really stupid about saying this, but what's an MWE?

Comment: @handuel that is not a stupid question at all. It stands for [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: @Dan Thanks for telling me. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @handuel Could you also edit in the `.log` file you get for the MWE?

Comment: delete `[dvips]` and `.eps` then your example should work with latex (using the eps version) or pdflatex (using the pdf version) If it doesn't work it is presumably a problem with the image, but as a test use `\fbox{\includegraphics{figure}}` so latex puts a visible box around the space where it thinks the image is, if that box is wrong, suspect the boundingbox in the eps file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! That worked perfectly. Would you mind submitting that as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Hmm it was supposed to be a debugging aid rather than an answer:-), if removing `[dvips]` made it work you are presumably using pdflatex rather than latex?

Comment: Yes. Sorry I should have stated that in my question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Delete `[dvips]` and `.eps` then your example should work with latex (using the eps version) or pdflatex (using the pdf version) If it doesn't work it is presumably a problem with the image, but as a test use

```
\fbox{\includegraphics{figure}}
```

so latex puts a visible box around the space where it thinks the image is, if that box is wrong, suspect the boundingbox in the eps file.

---

The `dvips`  driver can include EPS files but not PDF and the `pdftex` engine used by pdflatex can include PDF files but not EPS. If you use `[dvips]` explicitly LaTeX will set things up for dvips so it will not work if you process the document with pdflatex. If you omit the option and the file extension, then a default option is taken depending on the engine used (`[dvips]` if you use latex and `[pdftex]` if you use pdflatex. In each case a default list of file extensions is defined, so if you do not put an explicit `.eps` extension in `\includegraphics` but have both `.eps` and `.pdf` available, latex will try `figure.eps` and pdflatex will try `figure.pdf`

Comment: As a bonus is it possible if you could explain why that works?

Comment: @handuel see update

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Ghostscript software. Please check the wesite
http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html

There are five different files depending on your operating system. For instance, if you are working in windows xp or 7, you will need to install the file for  Windows (32 bit). If you are using  windows 8 or 10, you will need the file for  Windows (64 bit).