# I can not insert images

Tags: graphics

I installed LaTeX using mactex2018.
But, my environment cannot display images.
The source code is following the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\LaTeX

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=6cm]{./figures/image1.pdf}
  \caption{}
  \label{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and log file

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.12.25)  25 DEC 2018 13:17
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 2
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: dvipdfmx.def on input line 99.

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/dvipdfmx.def
File: dvipdfmx.def 2017/06/24 v5.0g Graphics/color driver for dvipdfmx
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen103
\Gin@req@width=\dimen104
)
(./test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 5.
File: ./figures/image1.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<./figures/image1.pdf>

Overfull \hbox (117.72874pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 8--9
[][] 
 []

[1{/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}

]
(./test.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 583 strings out of 492649
 7277 string characters out of 6129621
 65028 words of memory out of 5000000
 4527 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 25i,4n,21p,181b,236s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/c
m/cmr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/
cmr7.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 19776 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 16 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 10 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

out put is no images.
[image]

Comment: Did you try `\usepackage{graphicx}` instead of `\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}`?

Comment: the dvipdfmx option can not work unless you make dvi rather than pdftex, but you are using pdflatex.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in comment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Images on latex not appearing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55301/images-on-latex-not-appearing)