# Images in LaTex do not appear

Tags: graphics, pdftex, jpeg

I know there have been quite a lot of posts about this already (like this one [Images on latex not appearing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55301/images-on-latex-not-appearing) or this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134187/how-to-add-a-jpg-image-in-latex), but my problem *seems* to lie somewhere else.

The question however is basically the same: Why are the images that I try to include in my LaTex documents not showing up? What I get is a pdf file with a centered box in the (correct) size of the image:

[image: This is where my image should be]

Here is my code:

```
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\documentclass[a4paper,notitlepage,draft]{report}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{small.jpg}
  \caption{MyCaption}
  \label{fig:MyLabel}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I am using pdflatex under Gentoo Linux:

```
% pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020 Gentoo Linux)
kpathsea version 6.3.2
Copyright 2020 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37+apng; using libpng 1.6.37+apng
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with poppler version 0.88.0
```

Generally I'd like to have a nice way of including any jpg or png image of any size in a pdf document. Because my image was a bit large (750x811px), I downscaled it to (150x162px) just to rule out a problem related to scaling by LaTex. Converting it to png didn't work either.

Converting the image with "convert small.jpg eps2:small.eps" to eps and compiling it with latex->dvipdfm didn't do the trick either; neither did using the graphicx package with or without pdftex.

I do not even get an error message. Here is the log: https://pastebin.com/jGnwbYd5

Does anybody on this platform have a suggestion, where the problem lies?

Comment: Remove the `draft` option from `\documentclass...`

Comment: Thanks!! That did the trick!

Comment: @leandriis as there is TeX and eTeX, now there is greg and egreg ! :)