# How to use a Mathematica plot saved as a pdf in TexMaker?

Tags: diagrams, plot, wolfram-mathematica

How to use a Mathematica plot saved as a pdf in TexMaker?

[image]

When I use:

```
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth, angle=0]{Graphs.pdf}
```

EDIT:

The image is really small, how do I fix that?

This is what I get(after stretched) :

[image]

Comment: This doesn't really seem to be about Mathematica nor TeXMaker, and more about "how do I include a pdf graphic in my document".  Have you searched along those lines?

Comment: I'd say it is to do with LaTex!

Comment: @Math LaTeX yes, TexMaker no.  But at the moment we don't know that you've saved it with that exact name (including case) in a folder LaTeX can see.  See for example [Images on latex not appearing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55301/images-on-latex-not-appearing)

Comment: Your code snippet is a bit more helpful (even better would be if you completed it so that it went from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` and was only 5 lines of code).  And the error actually gives us something to work with.  Is `Graphs.pdf` in the same directory as your tex file?

Comment: @ChrisH ok, I have a picture, but its very small, how do I fix that?

Comment: Probably the optional `[width=]` argument to `includegraphics`

Comment: @Teepeemm yes, I forgot to save it in the same directory, so that issue is resolved. however, the image is really small

Comment: @ChrisH the quality of the image isn't good, is there a better method?

Comment: Yes, you need to sort out your export from Mathematica, which I haven't used for 20+ years.  If the image quality is poor, that's to do with the source image and not the typesetting.  It sounds like raster graphics in the pdf rather than vector. Mathematica should be smarter than that but it may need reconfiguring

Comment: it is the size you specified, if you want it bigger than 40% of the text width don't do `width=0.4\textwidth`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code  for the Mathematica plot should include the `LabelStyle` like

```
Plot[{Log[ x], 1*(x - 1), 1.5*(x - 1), 2*(x - 1), 2.5*(x - 1), 
        3*(x - 1)}, {x, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> 750, 
    PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thick, Dashing[None]}, {Red, 
            Dashing[None]}, {Black, Dashing[None]}, {Black, 
            Dashing[None]}, {Black, Dashing[None]}, {Black, Dashing[None]}}, 
    Frame -> {{True, False}, {False, True}}, 
    FrameLabel -> {{"y", None}, {None, "Fraction susceptible"}}, 
     LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 24, Black},
    FrameTicks -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, -4}]
```

Your script for Mathematica should have looked something like this:

```
myplot= Plot[<code>];
Export["FracS.pdf", myplot]
```

to generate a vector pdf file.

If the output was exported as a file `FracS.pdf` and you include in your LaTeX file

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{FracS.pdf}
        \caption{Plot of the Fraction susceptible}
        \centering
\end{figure}
```

you will get

[image: ww]